# How to customize the Operation Triggers?

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, dynamics-ax-xpo

I want to customize the operation triggers in AX 2012 R3 Retail SDK. I need to catch the trigger and to write some business logic there in trigger class.

Can anyone please guide how to do that? I need to use the I-Interface classes as well which are used in Blank Operations.

Comment: Are you willing to modify the e-Commerce, the modern POS, the enterprise POS?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The two top Google hits on "operation triggers in AX 2012 R3 Retail SDK" brings information on how to [extend Point of Sale](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj937973.aspx) and how to [modify a trigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj937966.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Jan B. I have accomplished my requirements by operation. I was trying to execute specific piece of code before one system operation. What I have done is; I created the blank operation, and called that system operation after executing my code. And it went well.